# Finding complex square roots

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$ with $y>0$, I'm asked to prove that there are positive reals $u$ and $v$ so that $2u^2=|z|+x$ and $2v^2=|z|-x$.

This is the first part of my assignment, but I don't see how this works if for example $x=-1/10$ and $y=1/10$

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality: $$|x+iy| \le |x|+|y| \lt |x|$$

And hence $\frac{|z|\pm x}{2}$ are both positive, and you can find $u$ and $v$ by taking their square roots.

Answer (score 0):

$|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, so you want $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u, v > 0$ and:
\begin{align}
  2u^2 &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + x\\
  2v^2 &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - x
\end{align}

We can rewrite these as $2u^2 - x = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $2v^2 + x = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and so $2u^2 - x = 2v^2 + x$, which gives $u^2 - v^2 = x$.  So choose your $u$ and $v$ to satisfy that.

Comment: While this is a necessary condition, it is not sufficient. In fact, for any $x$ and independently of $y$, there are infinitely many tuples that satisfy $u^2 - v^2 = x$. However, each $z$ only gives rise to two solutions to the original problem for each of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thanks.  I was a little iffy since I didn't use $y > 0$ anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$, you have $x^2\le |z|^2$, so
$$
|x|\le|z|.
$$
In particular $|z|-x\ge0$ and $|z|+x\ge0$. So you just take
$$
u=\sqrt{\frac{|z|+x}{2}},
\qquad
v=\sqrt{\frac{|z|-x}{2}}.
$$
If $x=-1/10$ and $y=1/10$, then
$$
|z|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}.
$$
Therefore
$$
u=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{20}}
$$
and, similarly,
$$
v=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{20}}
$$